# how to improve jquery javascript elements with equivalent id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 5 modules with big equal js code, but only INT ID is different.

How to simple access to get one-style javascript jquery for all modules with dynamical id?
ok 3 int is num.
CODE eg:

```
$("#super_mod_519").find('form');
$("#super_mod_345").find('form');
$("#super_mod_430").find('form');
$("#super_mod_632").find('form');
$("#super_mod_234").find('form');
$("#super_mod_713").find('form');

$("#super_mod_519 .button input").val('');
$("#super_mod_345 .button input").val('');
$("#super_mod_430 .button input").val('');
$("#super_mod_234 .button input").val('');
$("#super_mod_632 .button input").val('');
$("#super_mod_713 .button input").val('');
```

Comment: Consider adding a class to all of these elements, say `super_mod`, then you can use a selector like `$('.super_mod').find('form');` and it will select all the elements at once.

Comment: PLS i want dynamicall solution, its real ?

Comment: your question is not clear. but if i understood your point of view, i would recommend adding a same class to all elements then used that for querying

Comment: I NEED #ID selector please

Answer (score 0):

If the `id`s are the key elements here then you could collect them in an array and simplify things this way:

```js
const ids=[519,340,430,632,234,713];

ids.forEach(id=>
  $(`#super_mod_${id} form`) // some action ...
);

ids.forEach(id=>
  $(`#super_mod_${id} .button input`).val('')
);
```

(In order for the above snippet to work we still need some HTML and jQuery of course.)

If you want to perform the jQuery-based operations at the same time you can of course run them both in the same `ids.forEach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector below will select all elements that start with an `id` of "super_mod_".

```
$("*[id^='super_mod_']").find('form');
$("*[id^='super_mod_'] .button input").val('');
```